# dynamic allocation of 2d array function

Tags: c, function, dynamic-memory-allocation

So I have a program in C structured in 3 files: **main.c**, **alloc.h** and **alloc.c**.  In the `main.c` function, I have the declaration of a pointer to another pointer to which I intend to alloc an `n * m` array:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "alloc.h"

int main() {
   int **mat, n, m;
   alloc_matrix(&mat, int &n, int &m);
   return 0;
}
```

In **alloc.c** I have the following declarations:

```
#ifndef ALLOC_H_INCLUDED
#define ALLOC_H_INCLUDED
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
void alloc_matrix(int***, int*, int*);
#endif
```

In **alloc.c** I have the function:

```
void alloc_matrix(int ***mat, int *n, int *m) {
    printf("\nn = "); scanf("%d", n);
    printf("\nm = "); scanf("%d", m);
    *mat = (int**)calloc(*n, sizeof(int*));
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < *n; i++)
        *(mat + i) = (int*)calloc(*m, sizeof(int));
}
```

But the program doesn't work. It enters some kind of loop and doesn't end.
If I allocate it in `main` it would work but I have no idea what I am doing wrong in the `alloc` function.

Comment: There is no 2D array, nor a pointer to one or something which can represent one! And being a 3-star C programmer is not a compliment.

Comment: If that was your code: please do not correct its mistakes in the question. If it was not, please repost the whole question with the *actual* code.

Comment: `alloc_matrix(&mat,int &n,int &m);` this is not legal C. What compiler are you using?

Comment: i'm using codeblocks

Comment: it runs for me,but the problem is that i can't read the matrix

Comment: What works for you? The code you posted, or the code you changed after a (now deleted) comment?

Comment: Code::Blocks is an IDE, not a compiler. We are still waiting for the necessary information. We are no debugging service.

Comment: The code of `main` as posted cannot possibly be accepted by a C compiler. The code of `alloc_matrix` as posted should provoke a warning, which is in your situation as good as an error. Work on understanding and fixing it.Tweak your IDE settings so that warnings are treated as errors. You want to add `-Wall -Wextra -Werror` to the compiler flags. It's the only way to develop in C and stay sane.

Comment: You'll make life easier for yourself if you return `int **`, instead of using an `int ***` parameter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the correct code. Your error was that in the definition of `alloc_matrix`, you used `*(mat+i)` in the allocation loop, which should be `*(*mat+i)` as, mat is a `int***` so the base address for the 2D array would be in `*mat`. Then you need to move by offset `i` and then de-reference that memory location for the 1D array.

Main:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "alloc.h"
int main()
{
   int **mat,n,m;
   alloc_matrix(&mat,&n,&m);
   return 0;
}
```

alloc.h

```
#ifndef ALLOC_H_INCLUDED
#define ALLOC_H_INCLUDED
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
void alloc_matrix(int***,int*,int*);

#endif
```

alloc.c :

```
void alloc_matrix(int ***mat,int *n,int *m)
{
    printf("\nn = "); scanf("%d", n);
    printf("\nm = "); scanf("%d", m);
    *mat = (int**)calloc(*n,sizeof(int*));
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < *n; i++)
    *(*mat+i) = (int*)calloc(*m,sizeof(int));
}
```

The code for the read function :

```
void read_matrix(int ***mat,int n,int m)
    {
      int i,j;
      for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
       for(j = 0; j < m; j++)
        {
          printf("mat[%d][%d] = ", i, j);
          scanf("%d", (*(*mat+i))+j);
        }
    }
```

The problem with it is that it only reads the first row and the it freezes.

Comment: It seems to work.But when i try to read it it only reads the first row.What can be the problem with the way i read it ?void read_matrix(int ***mat,int n,int m)
{
  int i,j;
  for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
   for(j = 0; j < m; j++)
    {
      printf("mat[%d][%d] = ", i, j);
      scanf("%d", *(*(mat+i)+j));
    }
}

Comment: @NickName `void read_matrix(int ***` The problem is *the three stars*. You don't need that many. The other problem is ` *(*(mat+i)+j));`. This is just nonsense. A matrix is accessed like this: **`mat[i][j]`**.

Answer (score 2):

```
void alloc_matrix(int ***mat,int *n,int *m)
```

There are two problems in this line. Neither is fatal but both are worth fixing.

First problem: A matrix in this program is represented as an `int**`. Why does `alloc_matrix` accept an `int***`? All standard functions that allocate something (malloc and friends) return a pointer to that something. This is an idiomatic way of doing things in C. It reduces your star count (being a three-star C programmer is not an achievement to be proud of) and simplifies the code. The function should be changed to

```
int** alloc_matrix( // but what's inside the () ?
```

The second problem is, why should a function called `alloc_matrix` prompt the user and read values? These things are not related to allocation. A function should do one thing and do it well. Does `malloc` prompts you to enter the size? Does `fopen` prompt you to enter the filename? These things would be regarded as nonsense of the first degree, and rightly so. It is advised to *read the sizes elsewhere* and pass them to `alloc_matrix` as input arguments. Hence,

```
int** alloc_matrix(int n, int m) { // but what's inside the {}?
```

What remains of `alloc_matrix` is simple:

```
int** alloc_matrix(int n, int m) {
  int** mat; // that's what we will return
  int i;
  mat = (int**)calloc(n, sizeof(int*));
  for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
     // here comes the important part.
```

Since we have simplified `alloc_matrix`and reduced the star count in `mat`, what should we do with the old body of the loop? It was:

```
    *(mat+i) = (int*)calloc(...);
```

but if we remove a star, it becomes

```
    (mat+i) = (int*)calloc(...);
```

which is an obvious nonsense. Perhaps the old line was a problem. The fact that it provoked a compiler warning certainly doesn't speak for its correctness. So how to correct it? There aren't too many options. It turns out that in order to restore sanity, we must leave the old left-hand side (written for the three-star `mat`) intact. Or, better still, use an equivalent but more idiomatic notation:

```
    mat[i] = (int*)calloc(m, sizeof(int));
```

So the entire function now becomes

```
int** alloc_matrix(int n, int m) {
  int **mat;
  int i;
  mat = (int**)calloc(n, sizeof(int*));
  for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
    mat[i] = (int*)calloc(m, sizeof(int));
  return mat; 
}
```

and it should be called like

```
mat = alloc_matrix(n, m);
```

It is often said that one should not cast the result of `calloc` and friends. But in this case the cast has enabled a warning which helped to find a bug. I'm leaving the casts in place for now.

There is another idiom for the allocation that does not require the cast, but also avoids the problem of types not matching.
Instead of using the type for the `sizeof`, you can use the dereferenced pointer as the type information is available in the variable:

```
mat = (int**)calloc(n, sizeof(int*));
```

can be changed to

```
mat = calloc(n, sizeof *mat); //sizeof is an operator not a function
```

Comment: Could you please explain precisely how the cast enabled this warning, and what the warning is?

Comment: @BradenBest The cast produced a warning because the type on the left side of the assignment didn't match the type on the right side. It turned out that the left hand side was wrong.

Comment: ah, to catch newbie errors. Although I'm pretty sure that if one fumbles the level of indirection on the type, they're probably going to fumble the cast as well. Aside from that, I think it would be in the askers's best interest to reduce the level of indirection and use a better design. An `int **` is hardly useful for a matrix, IMO.

Comment: Why not use `mat = calloc(n, sizeof mat);`? It is much easier to read and avoids the problem from the start.

Comment: @KamiKaze I guess that's because `mat = calloc(n, sizeof mat);` would be incorrect.

Comment: Sry I meant `mat = calloc(n, sizeof *mat);` And if that does not make sense either now I blame the heat....

Comment: @KamiKaze this is correct, some people prefer it this way. I'm just not used to this styls. Please feel free to edit the answer.